# Question involving 3d vectors and lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let
$a = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad b = \begin{pmatrix} -11 \\ 1 \\ 28 \end{pmatrix}.$

There exist vectors p and d such that the line containing a and b can be expressed in the form $v = p + d t.$ Furthermore, for a certain choice of $d$, it is the case that for all points $v$ lying on the same side of $a$ that $b$ lies on, the distance between $v$ and $a$ is $t$. Find $d$.

Would d be some multiple of$\begin{pmatrix} -4 \\ 1 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix}$? What I did was just find the difference between the two points a and b. I'm really not sure how to do this....and I don't really understand what they are asking for in the first place.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You seem like you're on the right track.
Take note of the part that says : "for all points v... the distance between v and a is t."
t is a parameter in the line v=p+dt -- What does that tell you about d? What about p?